# Products Titles from Category Displayed as H2 - CS-Cart

Tags: product, h2

What file needs to be edited in CS-Cart so i can display products titles as H2 in category?

This is the good cod?

```
<h2 class="ty-product-list__item-name">
    {assign var="name" value="name_$obj_id"}
    {$smarty.capture.$name nofilter}
</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a nit general. What CS-Cart version are you using?
Could you send a link of your website category page, so I could see the h1 you want to change to h2?
Generally, you could find the h1 html tag in this path:

```
design/themes/responsive/templates/blocks/wrappers/mainbox_general.tpl
```

where responsive is the fedault theme cs-cart is using (unless you have changed to another one) and
**mainbox_general.tpl** is one of the five dropdown options you have inside the blocks

```
mainbox_general.tpl
mainbox_simple.tpl
onclick_dropdown.tpl
sidebox_general.tpl
sidebox_important.tpl
```

the above tpl files are the options you have inside the block at "Layouts -> Layouts" **Categories** tab "Main Content" block